# Only keep certain rows in group from specific value to max in that group

Tags: pandas, group-by, row, apply

I have a large df with keys that occur multiple times and values. Here is an example:

```
index key  value
0     1    346
1     1    349
2     1    351
3     1    353
4     1    355
5     2    359
6     2    359
7     2    360
8     2    365
9     2    365
10    2    366
11    2    369
```

I identified one value in each keys-group (for example: key 1:value 349, key 2:value 365) and want to apply a function that only retains the rows in each group from that specific value to the max value in that group (for example from group 1 the rows from index 2-5 must remain and from group 2 the rows from index 9 to 12 shall remain) leaving the following:

```
index  key  value
2    1    349
3    1    351
4    1    353
5    1    355
9    2    365
10    2    365
11    2    366
12    2    369
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

I tried using groupby.apply but as each identified value in each group is different, I think I rather need a for loop or something. Generally speaking I think I have a tuple where each value belongs to a specific key.

I cannot figure out how it works. Please help!!

Comment: can you provide your input as text/DataFrame?

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74415104/edit) your question

Answer (score 3):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) the threshold and use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to keep the values greater or equal:

```
out = df[df['value'].ge(df['key'].map({1: 349, 2: 365}))]
```